# Wrong result implementing counting inversions with python

Tags: python, recursion, divide-and-conquer

I'm trying to implement the counting version with mergeSort using python, here's my codes:

```
def merge(inLeft, inRight):
    inversions = 0; output = []
    while 0 < len(inLeft) and 0 < len(inRight):
        if inLeft[0] < inRight[0]:
            output.append(inLeft[0])
            inLeft.remove(inLeft[0])
        else:
            output.append(inRight[0])
            inRight.remove(inRight[0])
            inversions += len(inLeft)

    if len(inLeft) == 0:
        output.append(inRight[0])
    elif len(inRight) == 0:
        output.append(inLeft[0])    
    return output, inversions

def mergeSort(inList):
    length = len(inList)
    if length == 1:
        return inList, 0
    left, s1 = mergeSort(inList[: length//2])
    right, s2 = mergeSort(inList[length//2: ])
    sortedList, s3 = merge(left, right)
    return sortedList, (s1+s2+s3)
```

I thought when I invoke it by `mergeSort([1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 6])` I would get `([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 3)`, but actually I got `([1, 2, 3, 4], 1)`, and when I inspect it, i found that the `left` array is always `<built-in function sorted>`.

I'm studying the Divide and Conquer algorithm, thus not good at analyzing the problem in recursions. Where might be the problems? How can I fix it?

Comment: It sounds like your actual code uses a variable `sorted` which is actually a built-in function in python.

Comment: @quamrana I checked the code again, indeed there's a variable `sorted`, but that exists in another function that doesn't participate the process. Updated the codes, now it's full scripts displayed beyond.

Answer (score 0):

```
if len(inLeft) == 0:
    output.append(inRight[0])
elif len(inRight) == 0:
    output.append(inLeft[0])
```

This only adds the first element to the output. Change to `output.extend(inRight) / output.extend(inLeft)` to add the entire array efficiently. This will fix your missing elements.

In addition, the `remove` operation for Python lists has `O(N)` complexity, so you might want to consider using a deque (collections.deque), which allows for efficient removal from the front of a list.

Comment: You may have misunderstood my intention, my implement is bit different from other inversion counting implementations. I go though the 2 input array, compare element, transmit the smaller one to the output array(so I `append()` and `remove()`). According to inversion's characteristic, when element in the left is bigger than the right, the numbers of elements left in the left could be added to the inversion numbers. Besides, thanks for the `deque` tip :D